# How to add/manage user claims at runtime in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4, claims

I am trying to use IdentityServer4 in a new project. I have seen in the PluralSight video 'Understanding ASP.NET Core Security' that IdentityServer4 can be used with claims based security to secure a web API.  I have setup my IdentityServer4 as a separate project/solution.

I have also seen that you can add an IProfileService to add custom claims to the token which is returned by IdentityServer4.

One plan is to add new claims to users to grant them access to different parts of the api. However I can't figure out how to manage the claims of the users on the IdentityServer from the api project. I assume I should be making calls to IdentotyServer4 to add and remove a users claims?

Additionally is this a good approach in general, as I'm not sure allowing clients to add claims to the IdentityServer for their own internal security purposes makes sense - and could cause conflicts (eg multiple clients using the 'role' claim with value 'admin'). Perhaps I should be handling the security locally inside the api project and then just using the 'sub' claim to look them up?

Does anyone have a good approach for this?

Thanks

Comment: Claims are about identity - not permission https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: Hi @leastprivilege Thanks for the link. The link does make your opinion pretty clear, but I am still slightly confused as in this video (which is part of a course you are credited with helping to create) claims are used for authorisation. The video is called "Claims-based Authorization with Policies". Do you disagree with this aproach? Do you have any links to info on combining IdentityServer4 and authorisation correctly? Thanks again  https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=asp-dot-net-core-security-understanding&author=roland-guijt&name=c80587ee-9819-4b66-b743-6273ca1f32ff&clip=1&mode=live

Comment: I haven't watched the PluralSight course. All I have to say is in my blog post. A token is not a good transport mechanism for permissions. If you decide to use a string collection (aka ClaimsPrincipal) to hold your in-memory authZ data - that's up to you.

Answer (score 5):

Old question but still relevant. As leastprivilege said in the comments

> claims are about identity - not permissions

This rings true, but identity can also entail what type of user it is (Admin, User, Manager, etc) which can be used to determine permissions in your API. Perhaps setting up user roles with specific permissions? Essentially you could also split up Roles between clients as well for more control if CLIENT1-Admin should not have same permissions as CLIENT2-Admin.

So pass your Roles as a claim in your `IProfileService`.

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly Services.IUserService _userService;

    public ProfileService(Services.IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (context.Client.ClientId)
            {
                //setup profile data for each different client
                case "CLIENT1":
                {
                    //sub is your userId.
                    var userId = context.Subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "sub");

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId?.Value) && long.Parse(userId.Value) > 0)
                    {
                        //get the actual user object from the database
                        var user = await _userService.GetUserAsync(long.Parse(userId.Value));

                        // issue the claims for the user
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            var claims = GetCLIENT1Claims(user);

                            //add the claims
                            context.IssuedClaims = claims.Where(x => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
                case "CLIENT2":
                {
                    //...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            //log your exceptions
        }
    }

    // Gets all significant user claims that should be included
    private static Claim[] GetCLIENT1Claims(User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("user_id", user.UserId.ToString() ?? ""),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email ?? ""),
            new Claim("some_other_claim", user.Some_Other_Info ?? "")
        };

        //----- THIS IS WHERE ROLES ARE ADDED ------
        //user roles which are just string[] = { "CLIENT1-Admin", "CLIENT1-User", .. }
        foreach (string role in user.Roles)
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role));

        return claims.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then add `[Authorize]` attribute to you controllers for your specific permissions. This only allow specific roles to access them, hence setting up your own permissions.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "CLIENT1-Admin, CLIENT2-Admin, ...")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    //...
}
```

These claims above can also be passed on authentication for example if you are using a ResourceOwner setup with custom `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`. You can just pass the claims the same way in the Validation method like so.

```
context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
    subject: user.UserId.ToString(),
    authenticationMethod: "custom",
    claims: GetClaims(user));
```

So like leastprivilege said, you dont want to use IdentityServer for setting up permissions and passing that as claims (like who can edit what record), as they are way too specific and clutter the token, however setting up Roles that -

> grant them access to different parts of the api.

This is perfectly fine with User roles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seeing that the answer is very recent: Any idea on how to add users at runtime?

Comment: @Wouter Vanherck Not sure of your use case, but do you mean registering new users to your system? Registrations are exactly the same as normal asp.net web apps without identity server (identity server is more for authenticating already existing users). It's only logins that will issue tokens and do validation for which you should call identity server. Check out the default Register function in the AccountsController for the default asp.net templates in visual studio. If this doesn't answer you question, create a new question on stack overflow and link it here and I'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: Hey @Nick De Beer, thanks for the reply. I'm actually only trying to use the identity server for the token it delivers. My users are in a 3th party API and can't be registered through normal methods. I'll still check out what you said about the AccountsController since it might help me anyway. Still doing some more research before I ask a SO question, but I'll tag you the moment I do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Wouter Vanherck No problem. You will have to explain what you mean by not being able to register users through normal methods.

Comment: @Wouter Vanherck Usually external API works the same and you setup identity server as resource owner type. You won't use identity server to register users, only to authenticate existing ones. So you consume your api (clientside) normally, call your register (anonymous call) that inserts the new user in your db. Then when the user wants to login you call your identity server endpoint  /connect/token. And I when you setup your identityserver you will need to setup validation that calls the API (securely - CORS and ssl preferred) to check if the username and password exist.

Comment: @Wouter Vanherck check my profile, I have a pretty thorough answer regarding resource owner setup (IdentityServer 4 register UserService and get users from database using asp.net core). You only have to change the userRepository.FindAync() calls to call your api, find the user in the 3rd party API and return it to IdentityServer. Hope it helps